# Google Sheets - Mailchimp API - Create Template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO:**

I am trying to create a template (custom HTML) using Mailchimp API according to [this documentation](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/templates/).

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR:**

- Took raw HTML of the template I created using 'drag-and-drop'. Tested it using 'code-your-own'. Saved in a variable in apps script. Used to the following code, with data set as that variable. I got the following error

> {instance=2fb8b5eb-f11c-4260-a958-f16e5bc7c98b, detail=The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array., type=http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/, title=Invalid Resource, errors=[{field=, message=Schema describes object, NULL found instead}], status=400}

- I then set the data to simpler HTML as shown below. I got the same error.
- I tried using an already created template (accessed through TEMPLATE_ID) and tried to edit that (just the name of the template). I got the same error though I am able to access the template. The changes I made were:

  ```
  var TEMPLATE_ID = 'MY_TEMPLATE_ID';
  var endpoint = 'templates/' + TEMPLATE_ID;
  var data = {
             'name': 'new test name'
             }
  ```

  In params

  ```
  'method': 'PATCH'
  ```
- I also tried to GET method to see the templates, campaigns, lists. I am successfully able to do that.
- I looked up the various answers on SO, one of them suggested using mergefields, I tried it too with the same error.

  ```
   var data = {
         'name': 'Test Template',
         'html': '<html><head></head><body><p>TEST</p><body></html>',
         'mergefields': {}
       };
  ```

**MWE:**

```
    function mailchimpCampaign(){

    // URL and params for the Mailchimp API
    var root = 'https://us19.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/';
    var endpoint = 'templates';

    var data = {
                'name': 'Test Template',
                'html': '<html><head></head><body><p>TEST</p><body></html>'
                };
    var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

    // parameters for url fetch
    var params = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'headers': {
        'Authorization': 'apikey ' + API_KEY,
        'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        'data': payload
    };

    try {
        // call the Mailchimp API
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(root + endpoint, params);
        var data = response.getContentText();
        var json = JSON.parse(data);

        Logger.log(json);   
    }
    catch (error) {
        // deal with any errors
        Logger.log(error);
    };
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is for future readers.

So while I was hitting my head on this error. I tried using `UrlFetchApp.getRequest()` and it showed me that `payload` was empty.

The problem was I had to `payload` instead of `data` that I was using.

Updated working code:

```
 var params = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'apikey ' + API_KEY,
    'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    'payload': payload
};
```